# Displaying an image on linux without running x

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, raspbian

does anyone know of a way to just display an image via command line or C? I can run video fine without running X with omxplayer but i would like to also display an image without having to load the desktop, either via C or something i can run from the shell

Comment: $ feh -x yourpic.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[fbi](https://www.kraxel.org/blog/linux/fbida/), a frame-buffer image viewer, might do the trick for you.

Otherwise, you could try [JPEG to ASCII](http://csl.sublevel3.org/jp2a/) for a rough viewing of JPEG images.

Comment: fbi worked for what i needed thanks

Answer (score 5):

[SVGAlib](http://www.svgalib.org/jay/beginners_guide/beginners_guide.html) might be what you're looking for - a C graphics library that works without X11.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to [SDL](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=13789) that works pretty well on many platforms.

And if you want to make some funnier things, try [PyGame](http://www.raspberrypi-tutorials.co.uk/raspberry-pi-game-programming-part-1/), it is very easy to display/animate bitmap on screen with it (and it is in python which is well supported on RaspberryPi).

Comment: I think SDL uses svgalib for all the heavy lifting when run outside X.